# How to add existing visual studio project to empty git repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, gitignore, git-bash

I have an empty git repository on the server which I can clone to my local machine using 
git clone. My question is, how do I add a new visual studio 2010 project to that repo? 
 
Concretely, I created a folder and named it "repos". Inside the folder, I run the following command on git bash to clone my empty repo - git clone  (pseudo-code), which creates a folder called EmptyRepo inside my "repos" folder.
 Now if I want to create a new Visual studio project, would I create it inside this EmptyRepo folder? In which case if I'm creating a WindowsForm project named GitTrial, my directory would look like -> 
**repos/EmptyRepo/GitTrial/GitTrial.sln**, which would be my solution file, and
**repos/EmptyRepo/GitTrial/GitTrial/** would contain a bunch of files like bin, obj, Properties, Form1.cs, Form1.Designer.cs, GitTrial.csproj, Program.cs 
Or would these files go in a different folder?

Also, inside these paths, where would the .gitignore file go?
Thanks!

Comment: This might help you. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-code-in-git-vs.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm actually looking to do this using the git bash and  not any visual studio tools - just wanna understand the interaction of a Visual studio project's files with git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that `repos/EmptyRepo/` contains can be added to the EmptyRepo repository, so yes your suggested placement of `repos/EmptyRepo/GitTrial/...` would work fine.

Before adding files to the repo, I first recommend creating a `.gitignore` file at `repos/EmptyRepo/.gitignore`, in which you can ignore user-specific and generated Visual Studio files.  [Here is a public .gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) that contains a suggested Visual Studio .gitignore.

Next, use [git add](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) to add whatever files you want to include in the repository. Ex:  `git add GitTrial/GitTrial.sln` to add an individual file, or `git add GitTrial` to add the entire directory and its children, excluding those in the .gitignore.

Lastly, `git commit` your changes and `git push` to the remote EmptyRepo repository.